# Variavel JS dentro da tag html dentro do Blade Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel-blade

Preciso fazer com que o valor coletado no option, complete o action do meu form. Seria algo similar a essa ideia, mas não esta retornando o desejado.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="pform" action="/registrar/{valor}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="post">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Registros</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input type="hidden" id="id" class="form-control">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_id" class="control-label">Tipo de registro</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" id="tipo_id" onchange="option(this.value)">
                                    <option value="1">Entrada</option>
                                    <option value="2">Saida</option>
                                    <option value="3">Retirada</option>
                                    <option value="4">Despesas Fixas Mensais</option>
                                    <option value="5">Despesas Fixas Anuais</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nomeEntrada" class="control-label">Descrição</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeEntrada" placeholder="Nome da entrada">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="valorEntrada" class="control-label">Valor</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="valorEntrada" placeholder="Valor da entrada">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_id" class="control-label">Usuário</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select class="form-control" id="user_id" >
                                    <option value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">{{__(Auth::user()->name)}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                        <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function option(valor){

            console.log(valor);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que encontrei é definir o valor do action de acordo com que é alterado o select, dessa forma:

```
function option(valor) {
    $('#pform').attr('action', '/registrar/' + valor);
}
```

Além disso, você deve mudar o action principal para:

```
action="/registrar/1"
```

Já que `1` é o valor padrão do seu select.